# Function instead of numbers, sometimes returns Null

Tags: php

Hi i have following code:

```
function GetID($d1, $d2, $d3, $d4) {
   if ($d1 == '3') {
      if ($d2 == '3') {
         if ($d3 == 1) {
            $randval = mt_rand(1,100);
            if ($randval >= 1 && $randval <= 33) $weathern = 1;
            if ($randval >= 34 && $randval <= 66) $weathern = 3;
            if ($randval >= 67 && $randval >= 100) $weathern = 2;
         }
         elseif ($d3 == 2) {
            $randval = mt_rand(1,100);
            if ($randval >= 1 && $randval <= 45) $weathern = 1;
            if ($randval >= 46 && $randval <= 70) $weathern = 2;
            if ($randval >= 71 && $randval <= 100) $weathern = 3;
         }
         elseif ($d3 == 3) {
            $randval = mt_rand(1,100);
            if ($randval >= 1 && $randval <= 10) $weathern = 1;
            if ($randval >= 11 && $randval <= 35) $weathern = 2;
            if ($randval >= 36 && $randval <= 55) $weathern = 3;
            if ($randval >= 56 && $randval <= 85) $weathern = 5;
            if ($randval >= 86 && $randval <= 100) $weathern = 6;
         }
         elseif ($d3 == 5) {
            $randval = mt_rand(1,100);
            if ($randval >= 1 && $randval <= 30) $weathern = 3;
            if ($randval >= 31 && $randval <= 45) $weathern = 4;
            if ($randval >= 46 && $randval <= 75) $weathern = 6;
            if ($randval >= 76 && $randval <= 100) $weathern = 7;
         }
         elseif ($d3 == 6) {
            $randval = mt_rand(1,100);
            if ($randval >= 1 && $randval <= 30) $weathern = 5;
            if ($randval >= 31 && $randval <= 60) $weathern = 7;
            if ($randval >= 61 && $randval <= 75) $weathern = 2;
            if ($randval >= 76 && $randval <= 100) $weathern = 3;
         }
         elseif ($d3 == 7) {
            $randval = mt_rand(1,100);
            if ($randval >= 1 && $randval <= 35) $weathern = 8;
            if ($randval >= 36 && $randval <= 60) $weathern = 5;
            if ($randval >= 61 && $randval <= 85) $weathern = 2;
            if ($randval >= 86 && $randval <= 100) $weathern = 3;
         }
         elseif ($d3 == 8) {
            $randval = mt_rand(1,100);
            if ($randval >= 1 && $randval <= 35) $weathern = 3;
            if ($randval >= 36 && $randval <= 60) $weathern = 2;
            if ($randval >= 61 && $randval <= 85) $weathern = 1;
            if ($randval >= 86 && $randval <= 100) $weathern = 5;
         }
      }
   }
   return $weathern;
}
```

And when i call this function:

```
echo GetID(3, 3, 1, 1);
```

It works as expected (i get numbers) but sometimes it returns Nothing.

Any ideas why this happens?

I'm new with PHP but i don't see any problems here

Comment: can you format your code so we can see it.

Comment: use === instead of == to compare integers. also some of your ifs compare the id with strings some others with integers; this article tells you why http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Comment: Initialize `$weathern = -1;` right before very first if condition.

Comment: Please fix your code. Nobody wants to read that.

Comment: If i initialize Initialize `$weathern = -1;` before first if condidtion, it gives me -1 instead of null

Comment: A recommendation: instead of stacking multiple `if` statements within each other, you can do the inverse to make it nicer. `if ($d1 != 3 || $d2 != 3) return null;` (I also combined your first and second if).  Now you can go though the rest of your `if` statements without that giant indentation and needless block.  Also, string `'3'` is different from number `3`.  Also, "nothing" is not a return value.  Although you may not see a text return value, it could be a NULL, an empty string, spaces, or some undefined value.  Use `vardump()` to see what your variable contains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$randval >= 67 && $randval >= 100
```

is wrong, use

```
$randval >= 67 && $randval <= 100
```

instead.